# snowflake - select all columns without writing out each column and unnest one

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello I need to create a new table, from another table that has a nested column (EX: `metrics` col.) that I need to unnest for the new table without writing out each column (because.. what if I have 100 columns):

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT sales_uk, sales_ca, sales_sp, sales_us, sales, metrics[0]:category::string FROM og_table
```

is there another way? I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
select io.metrics[0]:category::string  as new_id, io.* 
from og_table io
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (that you have a variant column which you want to structure into a column for every object key) and it is acceptable to use copy/paste, then there should be an acceptable approach like this using lateral flatten of the variant column to produce a list of copy/paste-able columns for your new table definition.

```
with og as (select array_construct(object_construct(
  'category', 1,
  'bar', 2,
  'baz', 3
)) metrics)

select 'metrics'||metrics_array.path||':'||metrics_object.path||'::string as '||metrics_object.path||',' newcol from og
    ,lateral flatten(metrics) metrics_array
    ,lateral flatten(metrics_array.value) metrics_object;

--Produces output like:

metrics[0]:bar::string as bar,
metrics[0]:baz::string as baz,
metrics[0]:category::string as category,
```